# WebRTC: getUserMedia raises "NotFoundError" on Edge

Tags: webrtc

The following WebRTC code succeeds when using Firefox or Chrome, but fails when using Microsoft Edge:

```
socket.on('created', function (room) 
{
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function (stream) 
    {
        localStream = stream;
        localVideo.srcObject = stream;
        isCaller = true;
        }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error 1 ocurred when accessing media devices', err);
    });
});
```

The error is:

```
NotFoundError
```

I'm using this code to establish a 1-on-1 video chat.

How could I find out what I need to do to make it work on Edge, too?

Comment: what version of edge are you using?

Comment: Troubleshoot using  https://test.webrtc.org/

Comment: Make sure the Edge browser app has OS permission to access camera & mic. You didn't say what OS and version you're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, check If media settings are correct for the browser
- Troubleshoot media component here https://test.webrtc.org

To fill the compatibility gap  you can use [adapter.js](https://docs.w3cub.com/dom/webrtc_api/adapter.js/)

For each version of each browser that supports WebRTC, adapter.js implements the needed polyfills, establishes the non-prefixed names of APIs and applies any other changes needed to make the browser run code written to the WebRTC specification.

In order to use adapter.js, you need to include adapter.js on any page that uses WebRTC APIs:

**Using adapter.js**

1. Download a copy of the latest version of adapter.js from GitHub.
2. Place it in your site's directory structure (such as in your scripts directory).
3. Include adapter.js in your project:
4. Write your code, using WebRTC APIs per the specification, knowing that your code should work on all browsers.
5. Keep in mind that even a good shim like this one doesn't mean you don't need to test your code on different browsers (and ideally different versions of each browser).

Find more here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter

https://docs.w3cub.com/dom/webrtc_api/adapter.js/

Comment: Thank you. Can you still add the info that Edge may not be Chromium yet (low version number) and that this may be the cause? https://caniuse.com/#search=RTCPeerConnection